# Use an alternate /etc/ldap.conf with ldap search

Tags: ldap, openldap

I would like to perform ldap queries using an alternate file (which is intended to be used with pam.d and so have the same format as `/etc/ldap.conf`)

I think of using `ldapsearch`.  In the manual, I cannot find any help for this purpose.

Is it possible to perform ldap queries using an alternate *conf* file?

My `/etc/pam.d/myservice` use the module `pam_ldap` with option  `config=/etc/myservice.ldap.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding the /etc/ldap.conf just gives defaults for the parameters of the ldap utilities (like `ldapsearch`).

If you want to override that defaults you can specify them as command parameters when executing `ldapsearch`

See `ldapsearch --help`

Answer (score 0):

You should export the LDAPCONF or LDAPRC environment variable to specify the path to your file. See:
http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap.conf